# Corollary of Kronecker-Weber Theorem (J. Neukirch's ANT)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I have a question about the proof of Corollary (1.9), Chap V page 324 from Jürgen Neukirch's
Algebraic Number Theory:

**Claim:** Every finite abelian extension of $L \vert \mathbb{Q}_p$ is contained
in a field $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a root of unity. In other words:
The maximal abelian extension $\mathbb{Q}_p^{ab} \vert \mathbb{Q}_p$ is generated
by adjointed roots of unity.

**Proof:** For suitable $f$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$(p^f) \times U^{(n)}_{\mathbb{Q}_p} \subset N_{L \vert \mathbb{Q}_p} L^*$.
Therefore $L$ is contained in the class field / [the proof continues...]

About used notations: $(p) \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ is the unique maximal ideal
of $p$-adic integers and $(p^f)$ it's $f$-th power. $U^{(n)} = 1 +(p)^n$ and
$N_{L \vert \mathbb{Q}_p} L^* \subset \mathbb{Q}_p$ is the image of $L^*$ under
norm map.

Question: why such $f, n$ exist and now they can be found or their existence
be showed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $(p)$ is not $p \Bbb{Z}_p$ but $p^\Bbb{Z}$.

With $f = [L:\Bbb{Q}_p]$ and $p^{n-2}$ the largest power of $p$ dividing $f$
$$p^f= N_{L/\Bbb{Q}_p}(p), \qquad 1+p^n \Bbb{Z}_p= (1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}=(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^f=N_{L/\Bbb{Q}_p}(1+p^2\Bbb{Z}_p)$$

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, one identity I not understand. Why holds $1+p^n \Bbb{Z}_p= (1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$?

Comment: The binomial formula implies that $(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ is dense. $1+p^2$ has order $p^{k-2}$ in $\Bbb{Z}/(p^k)^\times$. Otherwise Neukrich uses $\log,\exp$.

Comment: What do you mean by that '$(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ is
dense'? As set in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with rerspect the
usual $p$-topology? If yes, how is it involved in your
argument? 

The observation that $1+p^2$ has order $p^{n-2}$ in 
$Z/(p^n)^{\times}$ implies that $1+p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ is
contained in $ (1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$. Which role
plays the density of $(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ here?

Comment: It is dense and closed, thus equal to $1+p^n Z_p$. The density follows from that any $1+ap^2 \bmod p^k$ is a power of $1+p^2$, and it is a power of $(1+p^2)^{p^{n-2}}$ iff $1+ap^2 =0\bmod p^n$ iff $a=0\bmod p^{n-2}$.

Comment: Ok, so in your claim above "$(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ is dense"
you claim more accurately that 
"$(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ is dense in $1+p^n Z_p$"?

But then I not understand the last part of your equivalence:
you wrote $1+ap^2 =0\bmod p^n $ iff $a=0\bmod p^{n-2}$. This 
seems not to make any sense. If $a=0\bmod p^{n-2}$ then 
$ap^2 \bmod p^n =0 $ and $1+ap^2 =1 \neq 0 \bmod p^n $, or is 
it a typo?

Comment: Do you really need help to spot that I meant $=1\bmod p^n$ ?

Comment: You are right, the last remark was superfluous. 
But I'm still not sure how your considerations show that 
$(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ is dense in 
$1+p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$. What you have proved now is that 
any $1+ap^2 \bmod p^k$ is power of $(1+p^2)^{p^{n-2}}$ iff
$a \in p^{n-2}Z_p$. But why does it imply the density of 
$(1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ in $1+p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$?
Which desity criterion do you apply here?

As far as I know to show density we have to show that for 
any open $O \subset 1+p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ the intersection
$O \cap (1+p^2 \Bbb{Z}_p)^{p^{n-2}}$ is not empty.

Comment: $(1+p^2)^c\equiv b\bmod p^k$ gives that $|(1+p^2)^c-b|_p \le p^{-k}$ where $k$ can be taken arbitrary large (for $k$ large enough $(1+p^2)^c$ will be in your open set containing $b$)

Comment: I understand it now, thank you for your explanations